# Dragging an element in HTML5 Canvas using mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a small program where I display a circle and allow the user to drag the circle within HTML5 Canvas.

I was able to display the circle but the drag functionality is working only if I click on below right corner of my circle, if I try to drag it by clicking on anywhere else of circle then it is not working. I am not able to figure out how to fix the issue in it.

Here is my complete code:

```
<script>
// handle mousedown events
function myDown(e) {

    // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // get the current mouse position
    var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // test each circle to see if mouse is inside
    dragok = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var r = circles[i];
        if (mx > r.x && mx < r.x + r.radius && my > r.y && my < r.y + r.height) {
            // if yes, set that circles isDragging=true
            dragok = true;
            r.isDragging = true;
        }
    }
    // save the current mouse position
    startX = mx;
    startY = my;
}


// handle mouseup events
function myUp(e) {  
    // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // clear all the dragging flags
    dragok = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i].isDragging = false;
    }
}


// handle mouse moves
function myMove(e) {
    // if we're dragging anything...
    if (dragok) {

        // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // get the current mouse position
        var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

        // calculate the distance the mouse has moved
        // since the last mousemove
        var dx = mx - startX;
        var dy = my - startY;

        // move each circle that isDragging 
        // by the distance the mouse has moved
        // since the last mousemove
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            var r = circles[i];
            if (r.isDragging) {
                r.x += dx;
                r.y += dy;
            }
        }

        // redraw the scene with the new circle positions
        draw();

        // reset the starting mouse position for the next mousemove
        startX = mx;
        startY = my;

    }
}
</script>
```

I guess, the issue is with `function myDown(e)` , but I was not able to figure out how to fix the co-ordinates so that if I click on anywhere of the circle it should be draggable.

Comment: You appear to be checking a box around the mouse position? Just check if the difference between the mouse and the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change in function myDown(e) the if inside for loop to:

```
if (mx > r.x - r.radius && mx < r.x + r.radius && my > r.y - r.radius && my < r.y + r.radius)
```